# Meteor 0.8.2 and debug.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have updated Meteor to 0.8.2 on an existing project.
I have corrected the various errors (Blaze template, and Meteor.render) that i could track in the console and the terminal but i get the following error in the browser console :

```
{#conestant}} is now unnecessary and deprecated. debug.js:41
```

I have no other indications on where the error is generated.
I would like to know where the error is generated so I could fix it.

Comment: It says that you should remove all the #constant regions in your templates as they are deprecated, see more info here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#upgrading-to-blaze

Comment: @imslavko that's correct. I have remove the #constant from my templates and the error is gone. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{#constant}}` is now removed. Previously meteor was not able to 'fix' areas of the screen you didn't want reactive. We needed to do this because jquery plugins would stop working when meteor changed the DOM.

Since 0.8.0 we no longer need to do this since the new rendering engine 'understands' DOM a bit better. You can safely remove it without having to worry about anything breaking.

The warning you see is a deprecation notice. `{{#constant}}` is actually ignored from 0.8.0.

Comment: Long life to Meteor !